# What is the meaning of {$C PRELOAD} directive?

Tags: delphi, directive, compiler-directives

I found this directive declared in Controls.pas (and also in other units) and I'll be glad to know what does it mean.

```
{$C PRELOAD}
```

As far as I know $C means assertions control but what is the PRELOAD keyword ? Is it something like "assert me at preloading time" ?

I found this in Delphi 2009

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `$C` directive is called  `Code segment attribute` and in conjuntion with the keywords MOVEABLE, FIXED, DEMANDLOAD, PRELOAD, DISCARDABLE, PERMANENT changues the attributes of a code segment.

```
{$C MOVEABLE DEMANDLOAD DISCARDABLE} // this is setting  Code Segment Attribute.
```

if you use the  [`$C`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Assert_directives_%28Delphi%29) directive with a `+` or `-` you are using enabling or disabling the generation of code for assertions.

example :

```
{$C+}    { Assertions - On }
```

Answer (score 7):

`{$C+}` and `{$C-}` are for assertions.  `{$C PRELOAD}` is a carryover from 16-bit programming, where it preloaded the unit's code segment into memory immediately at runtime instead of waiting for the segment to be accessed first.  That became unnecessary in Delphi 2 when 32-bit programming came around, so I don't know why the VCL source is still using it.